# Why in a similar situation water falls of even though from other side no air can come inside?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, surface-tension

In this [video](https://youtu.be/jJL0XoNBaac), Steve Mould mentions from 6:12 to 6:40 about how water tends to minimize surface area if we kept the one opening closed. Then why do we not observe the same thing when a water bottle is more than half-filled (not fully filled) and then we tilt it inverted (bottle opening is large in my case), then why does the water fall outside even though there is no opening at all in the other side. So how does air come inside to replace water? As surface tension plays the role of minimizing surface area, as mentioned in that part of the video, moving a little bit out gets its surface area more so why does water fall out of it?  Is it dependable on how small the opening is? A proof needed

Comment: I tried editing to make it a bit easier to comprehend, as the sentences were a bit too long (at least for me before editing). I suggest you to use this syntax in the future "Well that's what the video says, lets now consider this scenario X and we are doing this step named Y, the observation according to the video should be Z, but we know its W in real life" or somewhere along those lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch the video again and observe the mesh over the opening of the bottle.

The teapot has similar constrictive construction, largely due to the narrow path from reservoir to spout.  This allows surface tension do overcome gravitational force, less air pressure, in rough terms.

So, the physics is that the surface tension across a small-enough opening suffices act against gravity.  Keep in mind that air pressure tries to keep the fluid from draining (because it would pull a vacuum inside the bottle), and fails only when surface tension is insufficient to to overcome gravity. You will notice that the bottle drains in a pulsating manner as "bubbles" of air enter to relieve the vacuum above the fluid inside the bottle.